# Differentiating Cloud and Snow in unsupervised classification of mountaneous terrain?

Tags: remote-sensing, classification

I am doing unsupervised classification of a mountaneous terrain and I have used 500 classes to classify the land use.

In my result, **cloud** and the **snow** are categorized in the same class.

How do I differentiate them?

I want to eliminate the cloud but not the snow.

Answer (score 6):

First of all I should mention that this question is addressing very limited space, though important question too.

The first thing that comes to my mind on this subject that you can consider `temporal information` in short time interval. if certain values are changed in certain areas, it may be easier to detect snow.

and second solution is [here](http://www.nohrsc.nws.gov/technology/avhrr3a/avhrr3a.htm) from National Operational Hydrologic Remote Sensing Center (NOHRSC). they use a supervised image classification algorithm to map snow and clouds.

> Snow Can be Distinguished From Cloud at 1.6 m
>
> The 1.6 m wavelength allows significantly improved discrimination
>   between snow and clouds. At 1.6 m, snow has very low reflectance,
>   while the reflectance of clouds remains high (Figure 1). Therefore,
>   both cirrus and optically thick clouds can be directly classified and
>   distinguished from snow at the 1.6 m wavelength (Warren, 1982). This
>   has been clearly demonstrated using the operational Landsat Thematic
>   Mapper satellite, which has a channel centered near 1.6 m (channel 5;
>   1.57-1.78 m) (Dozier, 1987; Baglio, 1989).

and this image from the same place which shows Satellite channel wavelengths in microns (m), and typical reflectance spectra for snow and clouds.

[image: snowandcloud]

---

And results they get:

[image: result]